# Unwanted white space under image containing entry in IE

Tags: css, image, internet-explorer

There is unwanted white space under image containing entry in IE
I know this is one of the hottest questions and has been answered many times. I really tried every trick that I could find but nothing helped.
The bigger height the image is, there is bigger white space. If the image height is 100px, the gap is about 200px.

HTML (Wordpress php)

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`

```
<div id="main">
<ul id="postlist">
<li class="entry">
<div class="content">
<h2>title</h2>
<img src="http://" alt="04" width="681" height="382" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-137">
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#main ul {
font-size: 1em;
line-height: 1.4em;
}
#main ul#postlist {
margin: 0;
overflow: hidden;
list-style: none
}
#main ul#postlist li {
overflow: visible;
display: flex;
margin: 0.875em 0.5em;
float: none;
font-size: 1em;
}
#main ul#postlist li .content {
-webkit-box-flex: 1;
-webkit-flex-grow: 1;
-ms-flex-positive: 1;
flex-grow: 1;
border: none;
border-top: 1px solid rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.1);
background: none;
margin: 0em;
padding: 1em 1.2em;
box-shadow: none;
font-size: 1em;
border-radius: 0em;
}
img {
display: block;
border: none;
max-width: 100%;
width: auto;
height: auto;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

3. I have tried below CSS

   `img {
   float: left;
   vertical-align: bottom;/*or text-bottom or top or middle*/
   font-size: 0px;
   line-height: 1; /*or 0*/}`

Comment: Could you show the html code, at least with the img-tag and surrounding tags? (And also the relevant css for those surrounding tags)

Comment: Extracted relating HTML and CSS! Thanks @MartenKoetsier

Comment: From the use of `flex`, I assume you target IE11 here? If not, IE's before that do not support flex-layout (natively). What's more: the `img` has some WordPress-classes. From what I can see, these define all kinds of css-properties, depending on the theme you use. Without a digest of what's going on exactly, it's impossible to say what's going wrong. Your best course of action would be to use the [IE Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359) and find out what's going on. First, focus on what element the white space belongs to, then which class causes it.

Comment: I had a similar problem in ie 11 and none of the tricks worked. My .content was having `flex-direction: column` and changing it to `flex-direction: row` fixed it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding `min-height: 1px;` to `#main ul#postlist li .content`

If that doesn't work, trying using `flex: 1 0 auto;` instead of the flex-grow property.

We experienced this same issue while using flex to enforce a sticky footer on our site. We noticed the issue resolved itself when we added bootstrap's col-xs-12 class to the image's container. After weeding out the other CSS attributes, we found that all we needed from col-xs-12 was the `min-height:1px` property to make IE happy.

Cheers!

Comment: Genius! Thank you!